# AppStartError: Could not create the process "C:/Program Files (x86)/PokerSnowie/PokerSnowie.exe" Error returned by CreateProcess:

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I use python 3 and `pywinauto` to execute these three lines of code. But the system returns an error:

[image]

> AppStartError: Could not create the process "C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/PokerSnowie/PokerSnowie.exe" Error returned by CreateProcess:
>   (740, 'CreateProcess', '要求的作業需要提升的權限。')

But if I want to open another `exe` then there is no question.
[image]

What should I do now?

Comment: Try to add double quotes inside: `'"C:/Program Files (x86)/PokerSnowie/PokerSnowie.exe"'` so that space is not considered as separator between arguments.

Comment: Anyway try to run the same string in `cmd.exe` first to see if it works this way.